# How to convert from text to number without loosing symbol

Tags: excel, vba

Problem with code: I want to convert from text to number but in cell next to value I have euro symbol `"€"` which is then erased. The case is that if I do it through excel ("convert to number") euro symbol is not erased but every change with `.NumberFormat = "General"` or `"0"` erase the symbol.To have symbol at all I need to change to text firstly. Want to correct it to number so any operation is possible for user. Does anyone had this problem? Is it possible to change without erasing symbol?

Doesn't work:

```
With Range("G:G")  
    .Value = .Value
    .NumberFormat = "General"
End With
```

as well as

```
With Range("G:G")  
    .Value = .Value
    .NumberFormat = "0"
End With
```

Code:

```
Range("G:G").NumberFormat = "@"

i = 3
Do Until ws.Cells(i, 1) = ""
    If ws.Cells(i, 7).Value <> "" Or ws.Cells(i, 7).Value <> 0 Then
        ws.Cells(i, 7) = 200 & " " & Chr(128)
    End If
i = i + 1
Loop

With Range("G:G") 
  .Value = .Value
  .NumberFormat = "General"
End With
```

Comment: Did you try using the macro recorder to see what happens when the format is changed the way you want it to be changed when using Excel?

Comment: You could change to currency value instead of number value, and then the Euro symbol would be retained

Comment: Yes, macro recorder shows nothing in body of sub. Currency value still doesn't change format from text

Comment: Found solution. I needed to remove Chr(128) which was causing change to text and use instead of general format one of the euro Number format "#,##0 [$€-x-euro1]" or the one suggested by Plato77.

Answer (score 2):

If you're ok with currency format instead of number format, you could try:

```
With Range("G:G")
  .Value = .Value
  .NumberFormat = "[$€-2] #,##0.00"
```